# Android authentication with REST Service

Tags: android

I want to develop the Android client for my RESTFull Web service. But, I'm nearly newbie in Android and I don't know how to make correct authentication with REST service. How to save user details in android ?

Comment: Can you please be so kind to clarify your question? Title is very broad while the question in the body is about saving user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly complicated topic that is too broad to explain fully here. I highly recommend Retrofit for this. Here's a link to their site, http://square.github.io/retrofit/

I've also put together a sample project that gets images from imgur api using retrofit if you'd like to learn more about the implementation. 
https://github.com/mmeister1203/SampleRetrofitApp

Answer (score 0):

For authentication, I suggest you use Authentication token. It basically works this way:

1. You send user details to server(through https, of course).
2. You receive authentication token, which you save in, lets say, SharedPreferences.
3. Every time you make a web request, you include your token the request.

This is most common approach when you don't need extremely high security.